# How do I go about installing packages into Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda

I've been looking everywhere and cannot find a robust explanation.

I'm brand new to Python, coming from R. I had no issues installing packages there but I'm finding it to be rather confusing in Python.

So, I'm using Anaconda and I want to install [this](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud) package into Python. It mentions using the `conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/amueller wordcloud` command but I have no idea where I'm supposed to run it.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Run it from command line. You can directly install using pip as mentioned in the link. Don't forget to install the pre-requisite packages.

```
pip install wordcloud
```

If you are using windows, make sure your environmental path is set so that you can use the pip command directly from windows command prompt. Usually the environmental variable is updated when you install Anaconda distribution.

Conda is just another command which you can use to install packages. Procedure is exactly the same.

Comment: currently, i'm having issues installing it but I think it has more to do with the package rather than your instructions. I was wondering after I successfully install via the command line, can I just go straight into my python notebook and install the package?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to install directly. You asked where to run the command, that's why i wrote the answer. If you are facing problem regarding the package, without knowing the exact problem/error message, its difficult to say anything.

Comment: So, I was able to install the wordpress but it isn't registering when I try to install it into python notebook. I do see it in my python2.7 folder on my computer though.

Comment: Sorry to know that your problem is still not solved. Python notebook is just an interactive computational environment and it shouldn't create any problem for the packages installed in your local machine. Did you try without using the notebook? Though this check doesn't make sense but i am just trying to understand your exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find a package with a simple `conda search` from the command line, run a search on the [Anaconda website](https://anaconda.org).

In your case, you'll find that the contributor *amueller* has his own channel and the package *wordcloud* is [available](https://anaconda.org/amueller/wordcloud).

Just run `conda install -c amueller wordcloud=1.2.1` to install it.

You might want to create a separate environment using `conda create` first.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your response. I'm not quite sure what you mean by create a separate channel. Also, I think I see where my issue lies, I'm getting an error saying it isn't available for osx-64

Comment: @madhavt There's a misunderstanding. I suggested to create a separate (virtual) environment, And yes, it is `linux-64` only.

Answer (score 0):

You may install packages from interface
[Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLqSd.jpg)

Comment: How do I get that tab. That isn't showing up on mine.